# Drupal - different images for different languages

Tags: css, image, drupal, localization, internationalization

I have to "i18n" an existing drupal installation and add a second language.

I have an image on the homepage that is defined as a 'background-image' in a CSS file.

The image contains text, thus I need to show different images depending if the URL is:

```
http://example.com/en/
```

or

```
http://example.com/es/
```

How can I show a different image on the homepage depending on the user language (url based)?

I am pretty new to Drupal, so please don't assume I know anything!!!

*update*: I was hoping that I could define a particular image as "EN" and add an "ES" alternative, have one URL to the image (that can be used in templates or css etc), but depending on the user language, Drupal would serve up the language specific version. This would be ideal.

*update2*: Or maybe another approach is possible - to create a new 'content type' that simply contains an image so that: `http://example.com/node/23` returns the pure image binary (image/jpeg) - then this node could be internationalized/translated like other nodes. I'm really struggling to find the 'Drupal' way to i18n images...

*update3*: Does Drupal store the user language in the session? If so, I could just write my own script, read the session language and serve a language specific image right? and completely avoid Drupal (eg: `http://example.com/i18n-image.php?img=logo` - ugly, but you get the idea), if so, how does Drupal store the session user language?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the internationalization module: http://drupal.org/project/i18n

and use the function "i18n_get_lang()" to get the current language.

Name your files depending on the language:

```
image_LANGUAGE.jpg
image_fr.jpg
image_es.jpg
```

To embed the images:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_path().path_to_theme().'/images/'; ?>image_<?php echo i18n_get_lang(); ?>.jpg" />
```

**EDIT:**

To implement something similar for the CSS files:

You can create various CSS files depending on the language:

```
styles.css
styles_fr.css
styles_es.css
```

Into the main file (styles.css) you can put all CSS that is not related to a specific language.
Into the other files you can put the CSS related to a specific language.

styles_fr.css:

```
div.item1 { background: url('../images/item1_fr.jpg'); }
```

styles_es.css:

```
div.item1 { background: url('../images/item1_es.jpg'); }
```

And then you create a *preprocess* function for the page in your *template.php* file that will include the specific CSS style sheet based on the current language:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook){
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/css/styles.css');
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme().'/css/styles_'.i18n_get_lang().'.css');
}
```

Or you can directly use drupal_add_css() into a template file.

Comment: +1 This sounds pretty much like the easiest solution for you.

Comment: Great! That's more like it! Also, how can I implement something similar for within the css files? I'm new to Drupal, maybe there is a distinction between resource images (uploaded images etc) and site images (icons and backgrounds) - Is there a way to i18n icons? If so, I could use this mechanism?

Also is there a way to have 'dynamic' css in drupal (eg: styles.css.php), so that I can include the i18n_get_lang() function for switching css background images etc? (thanks for the answer, we're getting closer!!!

Comment: I updated my answer with an implementation for the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with hook_preprocess_page. For example, it can be a good idea to switch style sheets based on the language:

```
function foobar_hook_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $language;
  if($language != 'en') {
    $sheets = array();
    foreach($variables['css']['all']['theme'] as $stylesheet => $value) {
      if (strstr($stylesheet, path_to_theme())) {
        $stylesheet = str_replace('.css', '-'. $language->language .'.css', $stylesheet);
      }
      $sheets[$stylesheet] = $value;
    }
    $vars['css']['all']['theme'] = $sheets;
    $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($vars['css']);
  }
}
```

For further explanations, see this blogpost: http://becircle.com/language_based_stylesheet_switching_your_theme

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to change stylesheets - I dont want to have to maintain two (three, four or n) versions of stylesheets for each language.

Is there not a simply way that Drupal can load a language specific logo/image? Surely this is the type of basic feature that any multi-language website should have?

Also, I have absolutely no idea where I would put that code - inside a node? in my own php script? (thanks for the response)

Comment: you can use this code just to add a language dependent stylesheet like this:

    function foobar_hook_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
      global $language;
      $variables['css']['all']['theme'][] = path_to_theme() . '/language-' . $language->language . '.css';
    }

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend your answers for Drupal 7: There's a global variable `$language`that provides a standard class containing many information about the current language, including `$language->language` with the language short code.

It's defined in `modules/locale/locale.admin.inc`.

So call

```
<?php
global $language;
print 'images/'.$language->language.'/image.png';
?>
```

in your theme and catch all the "$language->language is undefined" errors.